# curl не видит cookie

Tags: php

Есть 2 функции,первая авторизируется на сайте и записивает результат в куки:

```
function get_html_skuba($url_4)



 {
        ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_4);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cook_2.txt');//
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cook_2.txt');//
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36");

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'google.ru');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // устанавливаем метод POST
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '__VIEWSTATE=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

  &dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtUsername=LcParts&dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtPassword=Lc754583&dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$cmdLogin=



');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cook_2.txt');
        $html = curl_exec($curl);
        return $html;
        curl_close($curl);
    }
```

вторая по идее должна перекидивать авторизированого пользователя на другую страницу:

```
function get_html_skuba_2($site_4,url_4)
{

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cook_2.txt');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cook_2.txt');//
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $site_4);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        //


        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36");

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url_4);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);


        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cook_2.txt');
        $html = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return $html;
    }
```

$site_4= 'http://212.91.12.186/emini/Default.aspx?tabid=54&v=29061&b=n';
$url_4= 'http://212.91.12.186/emini/Default.aspx?tabid=36&ctl=Login&returnurl=%2femini%2fDefault.aspx%3ftabid%3d36';

Первая функция работает отлично.Но вот вторая возвращает на страницу авторизации.Такое впечатление,что она не видит куков.Как решить эту проблему и перейти на нужную мне страницу?Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Укажи абсолютные пути до файла cookie.txt

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'/tmp/cook_2.txt');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cook_2.txt');
    // и включи header что бы видеть что приходит в нём
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

и проверь права начтение и запись это го файла. А так же статус запроса функцией `curl_getinfo()`;

Comment: сделал абсолютные пути,отчасти помогло(на нужную станицу перешел).Но со второй страницы мне нужно перейти дальше-делаю все в точности также как и в этом случае,а возвращает страницу авторизации.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 302-ответ в хидере